# How to solve isogram

Tags: python

Write a program that checks if a word supplied as the argument is an Isogram. An Isogram is a word in which no letter occurs more than once.

Create a method called is_isogram that takes one argument, a word to test if it's an isogram. This method should return a tuple of the word and a boolean indicating whether it is an isogram.

If the argument supplied is an empty string, return the argument and False: (argument, False). If the argument supplied is not a string, raise a TypeError with the message 'Argument should be a string'.

Comment: What did you try? Stackoverflow is not here to do your homework.

Comment: A little hint, use the `Counter` class from the collections module.

Comment: @Elmex80s: A little hint : `set(word)` is more than enough.

Comment: `len(word) == len(set(word))`

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
def is_isogram(word):
    return (word,True) if word and len(set(word)) == len(word) else (word,False)

is_isogram('assess') # ('assess', False)
is_isogram('rhyme') # ('rhyme', True)
```

Comment: Hi @Clock I've added edits to the code so that its more pythonic!